# React Native and Expo FS import issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expo, fs

This line:
        var a = require('react-native-fs');

returns the following error:
        JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text(53:22)

Thank you for your help.

```
import React from 'react';
    import { 
        StyleSheet,
        View,
        Text,
        TextInput,
     } from 'react-native';
    export default class Component1 extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
        textInputValue: "",
    }
}
render() {
    if (!this.props.visible) {
        return false;
    }     
    return (

        <View 
            style={styles.component}
        >
            <View style={styles.layouts}>
                <View style={styles.layout1}>
                    <View style={styles.itemcontainer1}>
                        <View style={styles.itemcontainer1Inner}>
                            <View style={styles.item1}>
                                    <TextInput 
                                        style={styles.item1TextInput}
                                        placeholder={"b"}
                                        underlineColorAndroid={"transparent"}
                                        placeholderTextColor={"rgba(0,0,0,1)"}
                                        onChangeText={(val) => this.setState({ textInputValue: val })}
                                        value={this.state.textInputValue}
                                        var a = require"react-native-fs";
                                        var path = a.DocumentDirectoryPath + '../textfile.txt';
                                        a.writeFile(path, this.state.textInputValue, 'utf8');
                                            .then((success) => {
                                                console.log('File Written');
```

Comment: Unless that line is somehow embedded inside a JSX expression, it is not the cause of the error. Can you show us more?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I'm new to programming.

Comment: The code you showed us is not the problem. In order to help you, we need to see more code. The error says the problem is on line 53, so please show us that line *and the code surrounding it*.

Comment: I edited the question to include the surrounding code.

Comment: Thanks, that has enough info to answer the question. I'll post one shortly.

Answer (score 1):

[JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html) is an extension to javascript commonly used by react applications. It looks similar to html tags, with angle brackets at the start and end of elements, and properties on those elements. If you want to put normal javascript inside of JSX, you can do so by using curly brackets. You've got examples of that, such as this one, which has some JSX for the View, then switches back to javascript to pass in styles.layouts:

```
<View style={styles.layouts}>
```

You're getting an error because you put javascript code in a random spot, without using curly brackets. Leaving out some of the extra stuff, you wrote:

```
<TextInput var a = require ("react-native-fs");
```

Which isn't valid JSX, since you didn't use curly brackets to switch back to javascript. Furthermore, this isn't the right spot to be doing asynchronous stuff, such as writing to a disk. The render method is a synchronous block of code which takes the current state of the component, and returns a description of what you want the screen to look like.

Where to put this code depends on what you're trying to do. If this is something you want to happen when the component is first created, then you'll want to put the code in componentDidMount, which is a function that react components can have to let them run code when they are first mounted. For example:

```
import fs from 'react-native-fs';

export default class Component1 extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var path = fs.DocumentDirectoryPath + '../textfile.txt';
    fs.writeFile(path, this.state.textInputValue, 'utf8')
        .then((success) => {
            console.log('File Written');
            // Possibly call this.setState if you want Component1 to render with something different now that the write is complete
        })
  }

  render() {
    // similar render to before, but without the file system code
  }
}
```

Or if this code is supposed to be run when they click a button, you might do it something like this:

```
onButtonPressed() {
    var path = fs.DocumentDirectoryPath + '../textfile.txt';
    fs.writeFile(path, this.state.textInputValue, 'utf8')
    //etc
}

render() {
  return (
    // other components omitted for brevity
    <Button onPress={() => this.onButtonPressed()}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. Will test this and respond soon!

Comment: Hope it goes well. I'll check back again, but i have some other things i need to do so i may not respond promptly.

Comment: I'm using React native with expo.

Just adding `import fs from 'react-native-fs';` 

causes the error

 `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNFSManager.RNFSFileTypeRegular')`, where there was no error before...